# GeoServer create geopackage mosaic

Tags: geoserver, geopackage

I have many rasters in a geopackage:

[image]

I want to publish all as one layer in GeoServer so I try to add a new GeoPackage (mosaic):

[image]

But I get the error
[image]

> The coverage store could not be saved. Failure message: Error
> persisting CoverageStoreInfoImpl[Orto] to
> workspaces/sdfsdfsdf/Orto/coveragestore.xml

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the data directory writable by the user running the GeoServer process? Also, what is the nature of the rasters? GeoServer only supports RGB(A) images, does not support raster grids of the geophisical type, e.g., DEMs )

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @AndreaAime the directory wasnt writeable. I changed it and it works now. You can add that as an answer if you want to

Comment: Does any of you know if it is possible to create an ImageMosaic from many rasters in one geopackage? I can only find examples using separate for example tif files

Comment: Nope, that is not possible, nor in the short term plans. If you have the ability to code it, contact us on the developer list, if you have funding for it, contact the commercial support providers listed at geserver.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to suggest your data directory is not writable. Try to change permissions on it.

Comment: (I set the environmental variable `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` to a folder where I have write permission)